# Make last image in slider pause before reseting loop (slider from scratch)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm working on a slider from scratch (trying to get the hang of it) but I've come up with a problem. In my slider all slides take 3 seconds before going to the next one, but once the last slide has been reached, no time to view it is given.

I want to add a smooth transition from the last slide to the first.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4wnrwkf0/

```
function startSlider() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        $sliderContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-=+100%'}, animationSpeed, function() {
            if (++currentSlide === $slides.length+1) {
                currentSlide = 1;
                $sliderContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
            }
        });
    }, pause);
}
```

I'm guessing my problem is somewhere around this code

For the time being I'm using a blank slide at the end...but I don't want to leave it like that :P

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I found a working solution by repeating the first slide at the end of the ul, seems a bit hackish so if anyone has an idea, i'm willing to try alternatives. Anyways...in case anyone finds it useful: http://jsfiddle.net/eclipticald/2gLh5ks0/

Comment: What happens if you increase $slides.length to 4?

Comment: @TobyAllen Actually if it's just 4 then it inmediately jumps to the first slide :(. By making $slides.length+1 i make a "fake" slide, but is not a smooth transition.

Comment: Am not sure if this is the effect that you want, but take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle if the effect resolved your problem -- http://jsfiddle.net/4wnrwkf0/5/

FROM:

```
if (++currentSlide === $slides.length+1) {
   currentSlide = 1;
   $sliderContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
}
```

TO:

```
if (++currentSlide === $slides.length+1) {
   $sliderContainer.animate({'margin-left': '0'}, animationSpeed, function() {
       currentSlide = 1; 
   });
}
```

EDIT. Another updated fiddle, so the last slide won't show the white/blank slide, instead goes to slide #1. http://jsfiddle.net/4wnrwkf0/6/

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! :D But it didn't solve my problem.

What I meant was the time that it waits on the last slide before sliding back to the first slide.

In your fiddle, once I reach saturn, it inmediately goes back :P. I can read earth and mars, but Saturn it shows for a very small timeframe.

Oh, on a sidenote. I'm actually trying to have it scroll in one direction only (right)

Thanks again!